# Checking if type matches nullable and non nullable versions

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I have to check if object is of certain type. ATM I am using following:

`columnLambda.Type.Name == "Guid" || Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(columnLambda.Type) != null && Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(columnLambda.Type).Name == "Guid"`

Which is long and 'clunky'. **Is there some built-in in solution to check for both?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(columnLambda.Type) ?? columnLambda.Type) == typeof(Guid)
```

or

```
(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(columnLambda.Type) ?? columnLambda.Type).Name == "Guid"
```

And of course if you want to check for a concrete value type known at compile time, you could simply do it w/o reflection as in @Lee answer.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, this is so much better than what I am using ATM.

Answer (score 1):

You can match the types directly instead of through their names:

```
columnLambda.Type == typeof(Guid) || columnLambda.Type == typeof(Guid?)
```